# What are the Data- API limits for Dailymotion API

Tags: live-streaming, dailymotion-api

Im trying to develop an app with live streaming features using Dailymotion API. Is there any limits for concurrent live streams(uploads or viewers), bandwidth or storage within the same logged user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the time being, all stream_*_url fields are rate-limited to 50 calls per day per API key.

https://developer.dailymotion.com/api#rate-limit

Answer (score 2):

There's no limitation for the viewer on the Dailymotion Live Platform. From the broadcaster side, we have a few number of limitations for the streams configuration:

- Maximum video bitrate: 10 mbp/s
- Maximum audio bitrate: 500 kbp/s

We also have some limitations on the maximum number of lives/videos that a user can create/upload which is set to 96 per day and per account.

Does this answer your question?

Comment: Yes, it completes the above answer. thanks for your help.